# SQLite3 - One cell has different type than other cells in column

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a `SQLite3` db. I use **SQLite Browser** and Python to work with this db. I have a column `description` which is a text column on the tabe. I've changed the text in one row using **Sqlite3 Browser**. From then, I'm getting error in python script.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried to catch this exception and print the row and I realised that instead of text, there is object buffer (this is just one cell) other cells in row are ok:

```
<read-write buffer ptr 0x047684B0, size 4307 at 0x04768490>
```

This is the only cell with this object, the cells I didn't modified are unicode's.

How to solve this issue? Is there some way to convert buffer to string in the database?

EDIT: python code

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    for row in connection.execute('SELECT * FROM final_table'):
        try:
            if any(x in ' '.join(unicode(y) for y in row[:2]+row[3:4]+row[5:13]+row[14:]) for x in ('mm445','xxs', '998s54a')):
                print row[:2]+row[3:4]+row[5:13]+row[14:]
                for x in row:
                    print type(x)
        except:
            print 'exc'
            print row[:2]+row[3:4]+row[5:13]+row[14:]
```

Comment: The problem appears to be that there is a non-ASCII character in the value. Show the code that tries to read it.

Comment: I've added the code at the bottom of the question. It check's for substrings in certain columns. The problem is that I'm going to import the db to the ecommerce so this row could cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unicode()` to convert a byte string from some encoding to Unicode, but unless you specifiy the encoding, Python assumes it's ASCII.

SQLite does not use ASCII but UTF-8, so you have to tell Python about it:

```
...join(unicode(y, 'UTF-8') for y in ...)
```

Comment: Changed to: any(x in ' '.join(unicode(y, 'UTF-8') for y in row ... ad raises TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found. But I need it to convert inside database. Is it possible?

Comment: Then you have some integer values in the DB. That is another problem.

Comment: It was because of id, when I excluded id, it raises: TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: But that is probably not the `unicode()` call. Why are you trying to use Unicode anyway?